# Running shell module multiple times in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a shell script (script1) multiple times with different arguments using ansible shell module. But the task should fail and exit if any of the commands fail with return code other than 0. This is I have so far.

```
- name: Run scripts
  shell: "{{ item}}"
  register: rslt
  until: rslt.rc != 0
  with_items:
    - "./script1 -f add1"
    - "./script1 -f add2"
    - "./script1 -f add3"
```

This task always runs the script 3 times even if the first one fails with return code (rslt.rc) other than 0. I want the task to fail and quit without running the subsequent items in with_items if the current execution of the script returns with a return code other than 0. For example, if the first item ("./script1 -f add1") fails, I don't want 2nd and 3rd items to run and ansible task should fail.

I greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the recommended solution for 1.9 is to separate out the tasks into individual calls.

There is some [past discussion](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1312) on this in Github.

You can achieve this in 2.0+ by using a when clause instead of an until.

This will skip the remaining tasks after you find a non-zero return code:

```
- name: Run scripts
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  register: rslt
  when: rslt is undefined or rslt.rc == 0
  with_items:
     ...
```

Example output:

```
TASK [Run scripts] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=exit 0)
changed: [localhost] => (item=exit 0)
failed: [localhost] (item=exit 1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "exit 1",  "delta": "0:00:00.004414", "end": "2016-12-08 13:14:06.365437", "failed": true, "item": "exit 1", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-12-08 13:14:06.361023", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=exit 0)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=exit 0)
```

Comment: I tried 'when' but it does not skip remaining tasks after a non-zero return code. Does this have anything to do with ansible version? I have ansible 1.9.

Comment: Hey @hmdb, just ran it on 1.9.4 and can verify that my solution does not work for this older version. Let me see if I can work something up for 1.9

Comment: Thanks @Rob Wagner